# Let $a,b$ be in a group $G$. Show $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $ab=ba$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a,b\in G$.  Show $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $ab=ba$.

I don't known where to start. It seems trivially.

Comment: If the equality holds for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, it holds specifically for $n=2$. What does that imply? - And if $ab=ba$ then the subgroup generated by $a,b$ is abelian.

Comment: That $(ab)^2=a^2b^2=b^2a^2$? I don't know if I can say that. If I can, why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Use $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ (you have $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so it works for negative numbers too).
- Another approach would be to manipulate $abab = aabb$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: +1 Note that even to prove this for $n\in\Bbb N$ only, you need inverses. The implication $\forall n\in\Bbb N: (ab)^n=a^nb^n\implies ab=ba$ is not valid for monoids.

Answer (score 10):

$ab=ba\Rightarrow (ab)^n=\underbrace{ab.ab.ab\cdots ab}_{n\text{ times}}=a(ba)(ba)(ba)\cdots(ba).b=a^nb^n$ replacing $ba$ by $ab$.

Conversely $(ab)^n=a^nb^n,~~\forall n$, so $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$. Multiplying this equation on the right by $b^{-1}$ and on the left by $a^{-1}$, then we have get $ab=ba$.

Comment: do you mean $(ab)^2$ instead of $(ab^2)$? (Can't edit your post)

Comment: yeah, of course. Sorry for the typo...

Comment: The first part only works as written when $n \geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Groups satisfying the condition $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ are known as $n$-abelian groups. The following is known:

> Let $G$ be a group and suppose that there exist three consecutive positive integers $n$ for which $G$ is $n$-abelian. Then $G$ is a commutative group.

For a nice proof, see Howard E. Bell, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 55, No. 3 (May, 1982).

Comment: While this does not answer the question, it does add useful information, so it deserves to be preserved. Plus, it tells the reader where to find a proof, so it is almost an answer.

Answer (score 1):

$(ab)^n=a^n b^n\implies (ba)^{n-1}=a^{n-1}b^{n-1}\implies b^{n-1}a^{n-1}=a^{n-1}b^{n-1}$.

Now put $n=2$.

This proves $G$ is abelian if $(ab)^n=a^n b^n$.

Proving that $(ab)^n= a^n b^n$ if $G$ is abelian is elementary.

Comment: It is only $\langle a,b\rangle\subseteq G$ that is known the be Abelian.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse direction can be done via straightforward induction too. Assume that $ab=ba$, let $P(n)$ be the statement that $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$, the base case is satisfied evidently. The inductive hypothesis; assume that for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $(ab)^k = a^kb^k$. We want to show that $(ab)^{k+1} = a^{k+1}b^{k+1}$, and to do this you could technically do another induction to show that for commuting elements $a,b \in G$ we have that $ab^{k+1} = b^{k+1}a$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, but it's as straightforward as this one so I'll omit it. Continuing from the inductive hypothesis it's straightforward to see that
$$
\begin{align}
(ab)^k(ab) &= a^kb^kab \\
(ab)^{k+1} &= a^kab^kb \\
&=a^{k+1}b^{k+1}.
\end{align}
$$
To show this works for negative integers you can just modify the inductive statement to $P(-n)$; specifically $(ab)^{-n} = a^{-n}b^{-n}$ and then induct on positive integers again.

Answer (score 0):

By taking n=2, we have $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$, which implies $abab=aabb$ and thus $ba=ab$. The converse is trivial.