# Showing $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ given $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is part of Exercise 2.1.15 of F. M. Goodman's *"Algebra: Abstract and Concrete"*.

> Let $G$ be a group. Suppose $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ for all $a, b\in G$. Show that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for all $a, b\in G$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

### My Attempt:

I'm using induction on $n$. Let $a, b\in G$.

Obviously $(ab)^1=ab=a^1b^1$ so the result holds for $n=1$.

Assume $(ab)^r=a^rb^r$ for some $r\in\mathbb{N}$.

Consider when $n=r+1$: we have
$$\begin{align}
(ab)^{r+1}&=(ab)^rab \\
&=a^rb^rab \\
&=a^{r+1}a^{-1}b^rab,
\end{align}$$ but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: Use the initial identity to prove $ab = ba$.

Comment: From the equation $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ premultiply by $a^{-1}$ & post multiply by $b^{-1}$ ... observe that $a$ & $b$ commute ...

Comment: Follow the comment of quasi and then use the result in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492332/let-a-b-be-in-a-group-g-show-abn-anbn-forall-n-in-mathbbz-if-an?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $abab=aabb$ you can get $ba=ab$, that is $a,b$ commute. Now you can rearrange any product between them.

Answer (score 3):

Since $abab = a^2 b^2$, then $ab = b^{-1} a b^2$ and $a^r b^r ab = a^r b^r b^{-1} a b^2 = a^r b^{r-1} a b^2$, and you can "shift" the $a$ successively to obtain the expression $a^{r+1}b^{r+1}$

Answer (score 2):

Following your approach, you can try a different factorization:

$$
(ab)^{r+1}=(ab)(ab)^r=aba^rb^r.
$$
Then, insert a $bb^{-1}=e$ just after the first $a$ in $a^r$.  This gives an $abab$ to which you can apply the original equality. 
$$
aba^rb^r=aba(bb^{-1})a^{r-1}b^r=(abab)b^{-1}a^{r-1}b^r=(a^2b^2)b^{-1}a^{r-1}b^r=a^2ba^{r-1}b^r.
$$
Continue by using (a second) induction to move the $b$ past the $a^r$, one factor at a time.