# Why does $ab = ba$ imply $(ab)^{n} = a^{n}b^{n}$ for $a, b\in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

I found the following post: [Let $a,b$ be in a group $G$. Show $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $ab=ba$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492332/let-a-b-be-in-a-group-g-show-abn-anbn-forall-n-in-mathbbz-if-an).

It means for $a, b\in G$, if $ab = ba$, then $(ab)^{n} = a^{n}b^{n}$. But if we let $G = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$, wouldn't this not be true? For example, take $a = b = 5$ so that $(a + b)^{2} = 100 \neq 625= a^{2}b^{2}.$

I'm new to abstract algebra. Maybe my understanding of what the theorem is saying is off.

Comment: $a^n$ means do the group operation to $a$ a total of $n$ times. So if $G = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$ then it means $na$, and the given identity translates to $n(a + b) = na + nb$ which is true. You're confusing the addition and the multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those annoying notation issues. Bear in mind that $a^n$ in a group $G$ with operation $\ast$ means

$$a^n = \underbrace{a \ast a \ast a \ast \cdots \ast a}_{n \; a's}$$

If $G$ is $\Bbb Z$ and your operation is addition, then the notation $a^n$ means

$$a^n = \underbrace{a + a + a + \cdots + a}_{n \; a's} = na$$

It's a bit confusing. In general, though, for abelian groups (those where $a \ast b = b \ast a$ for every $a,b \in G$), this is why we instead adopt the additive notation $na$ instead of the multiplicative notation $a^n$.

Thus, in this light, we have

$$(ab)^n = a^n b^n \text{ means } n(a+b) = na + nb$$

Comment: Thanks so much! This was really helpful